# How to save my crawling data on Django ORM?

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, orm, save, web-crawler

Im using bs4 for crawling news data.
At the first time, I made crawler function on views.py but it make error 504 error due to long loading time.

So, I decided to crawling and save data with Django ORM with new python file named 'crawling.py' in the same directory with models.

My crawler importing below functions

```
# from django.portal import settings
from .models import *
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as req
import ssl
from bs4.builder import builder_registry
import time
```

but it occurs error like below

```
(project) macs-MacBook-Pro:portalpage mac$ python crawling.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawling.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I found way to run my crawler in root directory but I will use crontab for batch jobs so I would like to locate my crawling.py inside app directory.

How could I run my crawler on back-end smoothly?

Comment: For your reference, My project name is portal, app name is portalpage. the crawling file located inside portalpage app directory.

Comment: Or is there any other method to make back-end crawling & saving datas? Ive searched was lambda & CloudWatch also but it did not helped me duh